# Django order_by Property gives error undefined

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am trying to order by (descending) average_score, but when i run it i get error: name 'average_score' is not defined. What am i doing wrong here?

error: name 'average_score' is not defined

model:

```
def _get_average_rating(self):
    reviews = Ratings.objects.filter(post=self)
    average = reviews.aggregate(Avg('score'))['score__avg']
    average = round(average, 1)
    return average


average_score = property(_get_average_rating)
```

view:

```
if sort == 'Average Rating':

    Posts = Posts.order_by(-average_score)
```

Comment: Please add the models `Posts` and `Ratings` to your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. and Posts is a queryset Post without the S is a model

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :-

views.py

```
Posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-average_score')
```

You didn't show your full `view`. So it is hard to guess if you're using an `id` to `filter objects`.

***Note** :- `.all()` will get all the objects from your Post Model.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

By using python's `Sorted` method like this:

```
Posts = sorted(Posts, key=lambda x: x.average_score, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot use methods in ORM queries. Secondly you get the error because no variable named `average_score` exists in that scope.

To do what you want you need to bring the logic **inside** your query instead of trying to use the method.

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(average_score=Avg('ratings__score')).order_by('-average_score')
```

> **Note**: Don't sort in python your database can do it more efficiently.

> **Note**: Also Model names should be **singular** so `Rating` instead of <s>`Ratings`</s>